# Count elements inside concatenated string

Tags: php

```
Example : string="abc,def,rst,xyz"
Output Should be 4
```

Is there a function that will count the number of values inside a concatenated string without the need for looping.

Thanks

Comment: Downvoting for a complete lack of own research.

Comment: I know how to count that but through explode and loop . Im just looking for some other way

Comment: If that's the case, you should post your code and state that you're looking for another solution, not just state that "here's my problem - solve it for me"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode` which creates an array with the comma as delimeter. No looping needed here.

```
$string = "abc,def,rst,xyz";
$ex = explode(",",$string);
$amount = count($ex);

//Will return 4
echo $amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Use it like: `$count = substr_count($myString, ",")+1;`

But couldn't the strings themselves contain a comma?
You should probably look into the csv functions, such as: [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and then do `count()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a string like `abc,def,rst,xyz`, you could do something like :

```
echo substr_count('abc,def,rst,xyz', ',') + 1;
```

Of course, this is assuming you have a well-formatted string. It won't work with strings like :

```
'abc,def,rst,'
',def,rst,xyz'
'abc,,rst,xyz'
// And so on...
```

Comment: By _always like_, I mean formatted like "text,text,text" (no matter how much texts you have).

Answer (score 0):

Try with
`$count = substr_count($yourString, ',') + 1;`